# how to install debian from a rescue cd (via ssh)

Tags: ssh, debian, xen, remote-access, rescue-disk

**situation**:

- server with RAID 1 (2x1000GB)
- currently logged in via SSH (network based debian rescue cd)

**need to accomplish**:

- install a debian based Xen (maybe with: http://wiki.xen.org/xenwiki/LiveCD ?)
- keep RAID 1

**problem**:

I have no physical access to the server, so i can't just drop in a cd or plug-in a usb drive. Does anyone have an ideas (or a tutorial handy) on how I can mount the LiveCD (on a read-only rescue-cd??) and the install the distru without breaking the RAID?

Comment: I can't tell you how to do it, but `debootstrap` http://wiki.debian.org/Debootstrap is most likely what you want.  "Breaking the RAID" is a vague term though, is it a hardware or software RAID?  I would assume that if the rescue CD can operate the RAID, the matching distribution installed kernel would operate the RAID as well.

Comment: I second `debootstrap`. It's a fantastic tool.

Answer (score 1):

["Installing Debian GNU/Linux from a Unix/Linux System"](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/apds03.en.html) from offical Debian documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do this sort of thing once, converting a remote RedHat box to Debian back in the days before readily available out of band management cards.

I'd recommend following [the good book](http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/i386/apds03.html.en) to get a basic Debian install going, then you can install the Xen packages once you're up and running.